# Pierce component style globally

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular7, angular-material2

I need to pierce the styles of my component from the global styles.scss file.

Basically, I've used `mat-card` component wrapped in a `custom-component`. In 
some cases, I want to change styles to the mat-card when a custom-component is preceded by another `custom-component`

The idea would be:

global-styles.scss

```
custom-component ~ custom-component::ng-deep { 
    .mat-card {
       background-color: red;
    }
}
```

The `host-context` seemed like a good idea, I tried it this way

custom-component.scss

```
// does not work
host-context(~custom-component) { background-color: red; }
```

I've tried this and some other combinations, but they don't seem to work. How are we supposed to use the >, ~, + selectors to style angular components?.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok not a solution for this, but there's one thing to consider.

If you want to apply styles to your component using the selector `your-component`, you have to set `display: block;` property in your component `:host`. I totally missed this, but it would look like this:

your-component.css

```
:host {
  display: block;
}
```

your parent component css

```
your-component ~ your-component {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

And it works. My problem was originally related to that.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I avoid piercing selectors at all costs. It breaks the entire component model, and tightly couples code.

I would approach this in a slightly different way. I would have my `custom-component` have an optional `Input() embedded = false`

Your usage could be as follows:

```
// top level
<custom-component></custom-component>
```

```
// nested level
<custom-component [embedded]="true"></custom-component>
```

Then use `ngClass` with the `embedded` property to trigger the color change.

See docs for more info on `ngClass` 
https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcewfr-nested-card-with-ng-content?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: This is a good approach, but not the one I intend. I know we are not supposed to use piercing but in this case I want to style components depending on the '~' selector.